# How can I set the value of border pixels after applying a sliding window operation?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, sliding-window

After applying a sliding-window operation like `stdfilt(i, ones(5, 5))` to an image in MATLAB, I would like to set the border pixels, the pixels calculated using padding, to `NaN` to mark them as meaningless. In this example, I would set the outermost two rows and columns to `NaN`. Given an M * M window, how can I set this border that is (M - 1) / 2 pixels wide to a specific value?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose, `r` is the matrix (result of `stdfilt`). Here is an example how to assign NaN to borders.
In general, you need to specify the correct index.

```
>> r = rand(4)

r =

    0.8147    0.6324    0.9575    0.9572
    0.9058    0.0975    0.9649    0.4854
    0.1270    0.2785    0.1576    0.8003
    0.9134    0.5469    0.9706    0.1419

>> r([1, end], :) = nan

r =

       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
    0.9058    0.0975    0.9649    0.4854
    0.1270    0.2785    0.1576    0.8003
       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN

>> r(:, [1, end]) = nan

r =

       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
       NaN    0.0975    0.9649       NaN
       NaN    0.2785    0.1576       NaN
       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

**update:** in general, since image is a matrix, your question is "how to set certain matrix values?". The answer is: "using matrix's indexes". There are many ways to do it (for example, by building matrix of indexes, logical mask, or using rows/columns coordinates). The decision what method to use usually depends on the speed of the operation for this specific task. For example, if you need to replace zeros by NaN's, it's faster to use a logical mask: `r(r == 0) = nan`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

First find where are `NaN`'s in your matrix. Assume your image Name is A.

```
a = isnan(A);
```

This will create matric `a` with 0 at locations that are numbers, and 1 at locations that are `NaN`. Then find the location of `Nan` elements as:

```
[x,y]=find(a==1);
```

Then replace them with value `V` as:

```
for i=1:length(x)
   A(x(i),y(i)) = V;
end
```

Comment: I'm not asking how to replace the NaNs with something, I'm asking how to replace the borders of the image (the pixels where stdfilt is computed from fake pixel values) with a particular value.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job, but this seems like the sort of function which would be in the image processing toolbox.

```
mask = logical(ones(size(i)));
width = (m - 1) / 2;
mask(width + 1:size(i, 1) - width, width + 1:size(i, 2) - width) = 0;
i(mask) = NaN;
```