# Matlab finding neighbouring pixels

Tags: matlab

How can I find the surrounding pixels of a certain pixel at location (x,y) in an image and then the outer pixels.

I then need to compare the surrounding and outer pixels with the center pixel (x,y).

Can anyone help me with this? Should I use a 3x3 neighbourhood?

Thanks

```
N = 16;
info = repmat(struct, ceil(size(Z, 1) / N), ceil(size(Z, 2) / N)); %creates an array of structs consisting of an m-by-n tiling 
for row = 1:N:size(Z, 1)%loop through each pixel in the image matrix
    for col = 1:N:size(Z, 2)
    r = (row - 1) / N + 1;% store the row index for each window
    c = (col - 1) / N + 1;%store the col index for each window 

    imgWindow = Z(row:min(end,row+N-1), col:min(end,col+N-1));
    largest = max(imgWindow(:));
    [rLarg, cLarg] = find(imgWindow == largest, 1, 'first');

    window(r, c).largest = largest;
    window(r, c).row = rLarg + row - 1;
    window(r, c).col = cLarg + col - 1;



  end
   end

200 034 234 245 211 222 214 245 234 234 211 222 211 245 234 234 
200 234 234 245 110 222 211 245 234 234 211 222 211 245 234 234 
201 234 234 245 211 222 211 205 134 234 211 222 291 245 231 234 
239 234 234 245 211 222 241 245 214 234 211 222 211 245 234 234 
221 234 234 245 111 222 251 245 234 234 211 222 111 245 234 234 
221 234 214 245 231 122 211 245 234 204 211 222 211 245 234 234 
014 034 034 245 211 222 211 245 234 234 211 222 218 245 234 234 
233 234 214 241 211 245 219 245 114 234 211 222 211 245 234 234 
233 234 244 245 231 222 111 245 234 234 211 222 211 245 234 234 
221 234 234 245 211 222 201 *249 234 234 211 222 208 245 234 234 
222 234 231 245 211 222 215 245 239 234 211 222 211 245 234 234 
222 234 234 245 111 222 219 245 234 234 211 222 111 245 234 234 
211 234 234 245 211 222 214 245 234 234 111 222 211 245 234 234 
245 234 234 245 211 222 211 245 234 234 211 222 291 245 234 234 
133 234 234 245 211 222 111 245 234 234 211 222 211 245 234 190 
234 234 234 245 211 222 211 245 234 234 211 222 211 245 234 234
```

Comment: How do you define `surrounding pixels` and `outer pixels`?

Comment: surrounding pixels are the pixels directly next to the brightest pixel eg (x+1, y), (x-1, y), (x, y-1), (x, y+1) and the outer pixels are then the pixels around the surrounding pixels.

Comment: `outer pixels` are again (x+1, y), (x-1, y), (x, y-1), (x, y+1)  with respect to each surrounding pixel?

Comment: I have added my code which finds the brightest pixel in a 16x16 window. It is the surrounding and outer pixel for each of the brightest pixels that I need to find

Comment: Is this related?: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22817286/2777181

Comment: yes, was advised to create a new question

Comment: I see, it's a bit hard to understand what you are after, could you draw an example of describe with equations? Maybe telling us your ultimate goal would help too.

Comment: yes my overall algoruithm is as follows: WHILE entire image has not been examined by 16 16 window
MOVE 16 16 window to next position
RECORD position and grey level value of pixel with
largest grey level in window
IF pixels surrounding the largest pixel are as bright as the
largest pixel grey level value
AND outer pixels are darker than the largest pixel grey
level value
THEN largest pixel position is the center pixel of a ROI
area
END IF
END WHILE

Comment: i currently have the locations and intensity of the brightest pixels in the image found by the 16x16 window. This is shown in the code above.  I now to check the intensity of the pixels directly surrounding the these brightest pixels.

Comment: All right, another question: do you have the image processing toolbox?

Comment: I have added a diagram to my question. Say this is the result from the 16x16 window- pixel 249 in the largest pixel found in this window. I now need to check the pixels arond this pixel 201, 234, 245, 245 to see if they are as bright as the lergest pixel (249)

Comment: It may be easier to do using [`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/images/ref/blockproc.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that it is what you want but after this line:

```
[rLarg, cLarg] = find(imgWindow == largest, 1, 'first');
```

You have the position of the center of your neighborhood, you can then access the neighborhood with:

```
Nborhood=[imgWindow(rLarg-1:rLarg+1, cLarg-1)', imgWindow([rLarg-1 rLarg+1], cLarg)', imgWindow(rLarg-1:rLarg+1, cLarg+1)']
```

*Note: you need to write a condition that will handle the cases where `[rLarg, cLarg]` are border pixels.*

Comment: this seems like what i need however i am getting an error: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or
logicals.

Comment: Yes, that is a border effect. If either `rLarg` of `cLarg` is equal to 1, then `rLarg-1=0` which cannot be used as a subscript index. See my note.

Comment: ahh ok, I am unsure how i should fix this by. Should i do it by assigning nan to borders as in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336113/how-can-i-set-the-value-of-border-pixels-after-applying-a-sliding-window-operati

Comment: That is an option. But now that you tell me that you have the IP toolbox, don't reinvent the wheel and look into this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/nlfilter.html

Comment: Thanks... so do you mean that i should apply a sliding window arround the largest pixel?